# Setting column width of a command output on AIX

Tags: java, bash, shell, aix

I'm trying to parse `df -Pg` command's output in my Java application, which will print for me as i want.

Here is the output of the command:

```
Filesystem    GB blocks      Used Available Capacity Mounted on
/dev/hd4           1.00      0.30      0.70      31% /
/dev/hd2           3.62      2.65      0.98      74% /usr
/dev/hd9var        2.00      0.19      1.81      10% /var
/dev/hd3           2.88      1.61      1.27      56% /tmp
/dev/hd1           2.00      1.30      0.70      66% /home
/proc                 -         -         -       -  /proc
/dev/hd10opt       1.00      0.27      0.73      28% /opt
/dev/fslv00        2.88      1.25      1.63      44% /tsmfiles
/dev/fslv01        2.00      0.84      1.16      43% /opt/IBM/ITM
/dev/livedump      0.25      0.00      0.25       1% /var/adm/ras/livedump
/dev/DoOnceAIX      0.75      0.00      0.75       1% /DoOnceAIX
/dev/nmonlv        1.00      0.03      0.97       4% /var/perf/poa
/dev/fslv02       49.50     42.86      6.64      87% /u01
/dev/fslv03      685.00    312.62    372.38      46% /u02
akslltsm:/depot     60.50     43.06     17.44      72% /mnt
```

My parser in java splits this text with spacing size. As it read lines, parser splits the string when hee sees at least 1 space character. As you can see, there are some lines inside the column (like "`GB blocks`" and "`Mounted on`") so i can't split as i want.

What i want is to set a column width (2+ space characters) and get my program to parse it successfully.

Comment: Why not just throw away the first line?

Comment: Good idea but not a permanent solution. I'm going to print lots of command output like this daily.Also i need first line in some cases.

Comment: @AloneInTheDark, skip the first line. Then, generate your own title line.

Comment: @sat as i told, i have lots of commands like this. So, isn't there any solution about setting column width?

Comment: @AloneInTheDark, there is no option in `df`.

Comment: Based on the last line, I think you want to split on tabs, not arbitrary whitespace.

Comment: Yes but there's not a tab for the last column. there is just one space character between columns.

Comment: @chepner there must be something i can do, with grep or awk, but couldn't find anything still.

Comment: Why would you want to parse the output of `df` in your java application instead of getting the info you need natively?

Comment: Because these outputs will be printed. I'm converting these outputs to an HTML file. I'm building an html table, so i need each column separately.

Comment: This is has progressed into a different request than the original.  It is not what you want the output to be put into columns but you need a way to actually parse the output.  parse implies "understand".  You will need a separate parser for each of the command outputs that you want to parse and understand.  e.g. what works for df is not gong to work for ls -l or mount or any other command.

Answer (score 1):

Catch the special cases and fill in the spaces, adjust the columns, then undo what you did in the first step.

e.g.

```
step one: sed -e 's/GB Blocks/GB_Blocks/' -e 's/Mounted on/Mounted_on/'

second step: your normal program that adjusts the columns

third step: sed -e 's/GB_Blocks/GB Blocks/' -e 's/Mounted_on/Mounted on/'
```

Then just pipe them together:

```
sed -e ... | <your prog> | sed -e ...
```

This is a fairly general technique for this type of situation.  If the input isn't able to be parsed (using whatever definition you need at the time), then alter the input to work, parse it, then reverse the first alteration.